# How to get value from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, helper

Sorry, My English is not good,

I have a View:

```
<div class="editor-field" id = "nick">Nick <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nick)%><img src="/Content/Images/loading.gif" alt = "loading...."/>
        <%: Ajax.ActionLink("Check", "Check", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "check-valid", LoadingElementId = "loading"})%>
        </div>
```

I used: Nick = ViewData.Model.Nick in ActionLink as below, but I cannot get value of Nick from View. Please help me

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("Check", "Check", new {Nick = ViewData.Model.Nick}, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "check-valid", LoadingElementId = "loading"})%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% using (Html.BeginFormBegin()){%>

<div class="editor-field" id = "nick">Nick <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nick)%><img src="/Content/Images/loading.gif" alt = "loading...."/>
        <%: Ajax.ActionLink("Check", "Check", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "check-valid", LoadingElementId = "loading"})%>
        </div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

<%}%>
```

In your controller your corresponding action should be something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyForm(string nick)
{
    //nick - should contain the value from the form

    return View();
}
```

Comment: In your opinion, ActionLink cannot take parameter from View, right? :(

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you mean? I appreciate that your English isn't great :-) can you include more of your code?